# binary Search to find closest float value to target number

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6, binary-search

I have some question and Maybe One of you can help me,
I have a float array and I won't find the closest float value to the target number(float)

I use a simple binary Search With javascript And from here I got stuck.

```
function binarySearch(arr, val, start = 0, end = arr.length - 1) {
    const mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);

    if(Math.abs(val - arr[mid]) < Math.abs(val - arr[mid + 1])){
        return mid;
    }

    if (start >= end) {
        return -1;
    }

    return val < arr[mid]
        ? binarySearch(arr, val, start, mid - 1)
        : binarySearch(arr, val, mid + 1, end);
}
let array = [0,0.03336667683886884,0.06673335367773768,0.10010003051660653,0.13346670735547536,0.1668333841943442,0.20020006103321306]
```

`let result = binarySearch(array,'0.166833')  //=>  This value needs to be returned 0.1668333841943442`

Comment: `Math.abs(val - arr[mid]) < Math.abs(val - arr[mid])`: what ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust  this arr[mid +1 ] My mistake

Comment: btw, why do you return `-1`? at least any value at left or right side is closest to the value, if not inbetween the given values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition `Math.abs(val - arr[mid]) < Math.abs(val - arr[mid + 1])` is wrong, you are always checking the left value is closer than the right value, so even for value 1 in array [10, 20, 30, 40], when you check number 20, 1 is closer to 20 than to 30 - incorrect result is then returned.

Also, you need to check the edge cases, the index `mid + 1` may not be available. Also the value may be smaller than the minimum or larger than the maximum, so an infinite loop may occur.

Let me offer you this solution instead:

```
function binarySearch(arr, val, start, end) {
    // edge case: value of smaller than min or larger than max
    if(array[0] >= val) return 0;
    if(array[array.length - 1] <= val) return array.length - 1;
    
    while (start <= end) {
        let mid = Math.floor((end + start) / 2);
        
        // value is in interval from previous to current element
        if(val >= arr[mid - 1] && val <= arr[mid]) {
            return Math.abs(val - arr[mid - 1]) < Math.abs(val - arr[mid]) ? mid - 1 : mid;
        }
        else {
            if(arr[mid] < val) {
                start = mid + 1;
            } 
            else {
                end = mid - 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stop condition is broken. In your example, if you feed the following array:

`[0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 2.0]`

You have at initiation:

- `arr[mid] = 0.5`
- `arr[mid + 1] = 0.8`

So if you feed `val = 0.1` to your algorithm, you will have:

- `Math.abs(val - arr[mid]) = 0.4`
- `Math.abs(val - arr[mid + 1]) = 0.7`

Therefore, you will return the index of `0.5` although you were expecting the index of `0.3`.

A pseudo idea to solve your problem would be:

```
if array contains 1 element => return element
else if array contains 2 elements => return element closest to val.
else if val < array[mid] => recurse on first half
else if val > array[mid] => recurse on second half
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have a typo. You should not return `mid` index, but item of array from `array[mid]`:

```js
function binarySearch(arr, val, start = 0, end = arr.length - 1) {
    const mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);

    if(Math.abs(val - arr[mid]) < Math.abs(val - arr[mid + 1])){
        return arr[mid];
    }

    if (start >= end) {
        return -1;
    }

    return val < arr[mid]
        ? binarySearch(arr, val, start, mid - 1)
        : binarySearch(arr, val, mid + 1, end);
}

let array = [0, 0.03336667683886884, 0.06673335367773768, 0.10010003051660653, 
    0.13346670735547536, 0.1668333841943442, 0.20020006103321306];
console.log(binarySearch(array,'0.166833')) // 0.1668333841943442
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution but I need to return the index of The right value

```js
function binarySearch(arr, target, lo = 0, hi = arr.length - 1) {
   if (target < arr[lo]) {return arr[0]}
   if (target > arr[hi]) {return arr[hi]}
   
   const mid = Math.floor((hi + lo) / 2);

   return hi - lo < 2 
     ? (target - arr[lo]) < (arr[hi] - target) ? arr[lo] : arr[hi]
     : target < arr[mid]
       ? binarySearch(arr, target, lo, mid)
       : target > arr[mid] 
         ? binarySearch(arr, target, mid, hi)
         : arr[mid]
}

let array = [0, 0.03336667683886884, 0.06673335367773768, 0.10010003051660653,0.13346670735547536, 0.1668333841943442, 0.20020006103321306,30.01]; 
    
console.log(binarySearch(array,0.03336))
```